# Leading zero and increment in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

I was looking on how to have a leading zero in ruby, and I found out the solution: use %02d"
Now, I'd like to do a loop, and keep this zero !
When I do something like this

```
i = "%02d" % "1".to_i
until (i == 10)
  puts i
  i += 1
end
```

I have an error "Cannot convert FixNum to string".
So I decide to do this

```
i = "%02d" % "1".to_i
"01"
until (i == 10)
  puts i
  i = i.to_i
  i += 1
end
```

So, this time, the loop work, but only the first number have the leading 0.
I ran out of idea, so I'd appreciate a little help !

Comment: in ruby the i += 1 is typically avoided, notice none of the answers given include that. .upto, .times, .each, .each_with_index will all be more common in ruby code

Comment: Don't forget to indent your code in future.

Comment: @Beanish Okay, I didn't know, thanks :)
@Andrew Yeap, sorry for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not a Ruby developer, but fundamentally I think you need to separate out the idea of the *number* `i`, and the *text representation* with a leading 0. So *something* like:

```
for i in (1..10)
  puts "%02d" % i
end
```

(As you can see from the other answers, there are plenty of ways of coding the loop itself.)

Here `i` is always a number, but the expression `"%02d" % i` formats `i` as a two-digit number, just for display purposes.

Comment: Thank, it's exactly what I need ! I saw the difference between the two things, and understand better the first error ^^ Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

Don't convert to a string for output until you're ready to actually output. You don't increment string values, typically.

```
0.upto(10) { |i| puts "%02d" % i }
```

Comment: That work fine but the Jon Skeet's solution fits better for my code. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: That's cool, but you probably want to consider whether your code really benefits from a non-Ruby construct (iterating with `until`). Iterating up to a variable fixnum like you're doing makes more sense with a closer-to-native loop (which happens to be Enumerable in Ruby) that is also more idiomatic (see above).

Answer (score 2):

```
10.times do |x|
  puts "%02d" % x
end
```